# Type-safe alternative for execute parameters in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

There are two ways to pass arguments to an `AsyncTask`

1. Define the first generic parameter and use a list/array of this typed and pass it through `execute()`
2. Pass all necessary arguments through the constructor, store them in a field and access them in `execute`

I find the first approach more readable, but sometimes it lacks flexibility in terms of type-safety, for instance if you want to pass a String, an Integer and a Boolean it seems unclear how to approach this.

```
public Result doInBackground(String... params) {
   String param1 = params[0];
   int param2 = Integer.valueOf(params[1]);
   boolean param3 = Boolean.valueOf(params[2]);
   // ...
}
```

String parsing, putting it in a `Bundle`, etc. There is always a solution, but I find this unpleasing from a semantic/method signature point of view. Any alternatives?

Comment: I use the constructor approach. And there's nothing stopping you from defining another method (or set of methods) on your `AsyncTask` to collect data in another way (e.g., give it a fluent builder-style API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a Class Holder for Example

```
static Class Holder {
  int i;
  String s;
  boolean b;
}

public Result doInBackground(Holder... params) {
   Holder holder = params[0];
   String holder.s;
  // ...
 }
```

then send it to the doBackground() through the execute()..
i did it a lot of times when i want to send to web

this is just an example of crouse.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) instead.

It can be cumbersome to start with, but you won't have any type-safe issues then, because it works in a complete different manner.

The main power of loaders is that they work with a manager that is bound to the lifecycle of the Activity/Fragment.